Getting the default firebaseapp already exists in .NET Core while sending notifications
We have implemented the notifications and it works fine when we do the regular testing. However, when concurrent users uses the same API then we get below error.
The default firebaseapp already exists. However, by checking the solution on the internet, we have implemented the below solution in the class constructor
if (FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance == null)
{
    FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
    {
        Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(<Passing Firebase Config here>))
    });
}

Then sending the notification using this code:
string result = await FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(message);

Still we are getting the error as default FirebaseApp already exists.
Any help on this is appreciated!

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

class FirebaseManager:
    def __init__(self):
        if not firebase_admin._apps:
            cred = credentials.Certificate('path/to/your/serviceAccountKey.json')
            firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
                'databaseURL': 'https://your-database-url.firebaseio.com'
            })
        self.db = firestore.client()

# Usage

firebase_manager = FirebaseManager()


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
